# How can I determine the velocity of a pinch to zoom action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios

How can I determine the velocity of a pinch to zoom action?

I have the gesture event, just need to pull out velocity.

Comment: *[posting as comment instead of answer because I'm too lazy to make an example]* You could use the time between the touchstart and touchend events along with the zoom factor provided with the pinch gesture to deduce a velocity.

Comment: @wildpeaks thanks, this sounds like it might be a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

UIPinchGestureRecognizer has a "velocity" property. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPinchGestureRecognizer/velocity)

Comment: Sorry for that, i noticed only the ios and iphone tags and not the JS ones. Shouldn't the question be edited to be more specific about this?